# Reflection of line on a sphere.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

How do I calculate the reflection of a line on a sphere in 3D? I.e. given the situation shown below, how do I calculate the vector *w*?

[image]

Where *C* is the center of the sphere, *v* is the direction of the line and *w* is the direction of the reflected line.

Comment: To clearify, v, C and X are known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $w$ is the reflection of $v$ in the line $\overline{xc}$, so simply take 
$$w=2\langle v,x-c\rangle(x-c)-v.$$

Comment: I always thought reflections in 3d are defined by planes. So how can I reflect around a line?

Comment: Everything happens within the plane spanned by $v$, $x$ and $c$, so you're dealing with a 2d situation. And just to keep the algebra simple you could translate the whole picture so that $c$ is at the origin.

Comment: Am I right assuming that the brackets "<" and ">" denote the dot product, so that the dot product will be applied on v and x-c?

Comment: After some trial and error, it seems that the formula is not entirely correct. I think the result should have the opposite sign, i.e. -1*(2(v,x-c)*(x-c)-v). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ahh I just got it know. So the reflection that is applied here will of course reflect the w in such a way that it will also point into the center of the sphere. Obviously, I wanted to model the reflection of a ray on the surface of the sphere. Then, I have to use -w instead, to make it "point away" from the sphere.